# Issue in installing stitch2d

Tags: python, pip, package, installation

I'm trying to install stitch2d with following command

```
pip install stitch2d
```

but i'm getting following error while trying to install it.

```
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/stitch2d.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing pip-egg-info/stitch2d.egg-info/PKG-INFO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-7fo41qxe/stitch2d/setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    zip_safe=False)
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 140, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 288, in run
    writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info, ep.name))
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 613, in write_pkg_info
    metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 1107, in write_pkg_info
    self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 91, in write_pkg_file
    long_desc = rfc822_escape(self.get_long_description())
  File "/home/gulve/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/util.py", line 471, in rfc822_escape
    lines = header.split('\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-7fo41qxe/stitch2d/

i have updated supertool but it still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stitch2d [works only with Python 2.7](https://github.com/adamancer/stitch2d/blob/f61239e155e63eac5660968bc2076f20a5016d51/setup.py#L16).